# -- Curl, terminal version, send POST and GET data at same time: how to?

Tags: curl, terminal

> (new user can't post link, so I strip all http:// from every link in
>   the example)

I have to send an associative array to a webservice (php), via curl terminal shell.

This service is not managed by me, and they ask to me to point to a particular php page and send my results via POST.

The page is something like:
www.domain.com/ws.php?authCode=xxx&action=yyy&id=zzz

WRONG WAY

```
curl -d "@filename_with_all_dataArray.txt" www.domain.com/ws.php?authCode=xxx&action=yyy&id=zzz
```

or

```
curl -d "value[0][0]=123&value[0][1]=234&value[1][0]=123&value[1][2]=234" www.domain.com/ws.php?authCode=xxx&action=yyy&id=zzz
```

or

```
curl -X POST -d "@filename.txt" www.domain.com/ws.php?authCode=xxx&action=yyy&id=zzz
```

or

```
curl -d "value[0][0]=123&value[0][1]=234&value[1][0]=123&value[1][2]=234" -G -d "authCode=xxx&action=yyy&id=zzz" www.domain.com/ws.php
```

... and all the other combination that I made. ;)

I try also with a local php page that answers dumping out the values (POST and GET), but **seems that it's possible to have the array via POST and only the first GET from the url (not the other after the first one)**

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: The first three should be perfectly valid. The fourth isn't. Are you sure there's not some issue with parameters needing url encoding in your get data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't quoted the url. It's not a problem with a single get parameter, but when you use several you use '&' which has special meaning in shells. In unix shells it's used to run a command in the background. I use it every day, but it didn't dawn on me until after having slept on it.